# Copy data to ANativeWindow_Buffer from Mat

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to copy the processed data in an `OpenCV Mat` object to the `buffer.bits` from a `ANativeWindow_Buffer`so that it can be visualized on the display.

I get a compilation error for this:

```
void CV_Main::CameraLoop() {
    bool buffer_printout = false;

    while (1) {
        if (m_camera_thread_stopped) { break; }
        if (!m_camera_ready || !m_image_reader) { continue; }
        m_image = m_image_reader->GetLatestImage();
        if (m_image == nullptr) { continue; }

        ANativeWindow_acquire(m_native_window);
        ANativeWindow_Buffer buffer;
        if (ANativeWindow_lock(m_native_window, &buffer, nullptr) < 0) {
            m_image_reader->DeleteImage(m_image);
            m_image = nullptr;
            continue;
        }

        if (false == buffer_printout) {
            buffer_printout = true;
            LOGI("/// H-W-S-F: %d, %d, %d, %d", buffer.height, buffer.width, buffer.stride,
                 buffer.format);
        }


        display_mat = cv::Mat(buffer.height, buffer.stride, CV_8UC4, buffer.bits);
        int radius = 30;
        cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar(0, 256, 256);
        cv::Point point(display_mat.cols / 2, display_mat.rows / 2);
        cv::circle(display_mat, point, radius, color, CV_FILLED);
        std::vector<uchar> buf;
        cv::imencode(".jpeg", display_mat, buf);
        std::copy(buf.begin(), buf.end(), buffer.bits); // HERE IS THE COMPILATION ERROR
        m_image_reader->DisplayImage(&buffer, m_image);

        if (true == scan_mode) {
            FaceDetect(display_mat);
        }

        ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(m_native_window);
        ANativeWindow_release(m_native_window);
    }
    FlipCamera();
}
```

The error I get is

```
    In file included from /home/erikbylow/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/array:109:
/home/myname/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/algorithm:1811:49: error: arithmetic on a pointer to void
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first, (void) ++__result)
                                                ^ ~~~~~~~~
/home/myname/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/algorithm:1837:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__ndk1::__copy<unsigned char *, void *>' requested here
    return _VSTD::__copy(__unwrap_iter(__first), __unwrap_iter(__last), __unwrap_iter(__result));
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want?